# Solve $2p = q + 1$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I efficiently solve the equation $2p = q + 1$ for prime numbers $p$ and $q$?

Is there a finite number of solutions?  If yes, what are they, and if not, how can I quickly find the solutions where $p$ is smaller than $n$, for example?

Comment: I have no insight other than a feeling that there is an infinite number of primes with this property (I wrote a small script to check and it seems to agree up to q ~ 100000)

Comment: @tehforsch:  What do you mean by "agree"?

Comment: [OEIS/A005384](http://oeis.org/A005384)

Comment: "It has been conjectured that there are infinitely many Sophie Germain primes, but this remains unproven."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime

Comment: @DavidG.Stork simply that it continues finding these prime pairs up to large values of q, obviously that doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I will point out that I was mistaken in my link.  Whereas Sophie Germain primes are those primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime, the primes the OP is looking for are those primes $p$ such that $2p-1$ is also prime.  Still, they seem closely related.  Looking for the first few of this other sequence of primes yields [the correct entry: OEIS/A005382](http://oeis.org/A005382)

Comment: @JMoravitz If I have not made a mistake the first few pairs are (1, 1), (7, 13), (19, 37), (31, 61), (97, 193), (139, 277) ... I cannot find these in the OEIS

Comment: @Tehforsch $1$ is not a prime number.  $2\cdot 2=3+1$, $3\cdot 2 = 5+1$.  You are missing $79$ as well

Comment: [Dickson's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickson's_conjecture) implies there are infinitely many.

Comment: @JMoravitz Woops ;) I'm tired ... I was missing a bunch of numbers actually ... 
(3, 5)
(7, 13)
(19, 37)
(31, 61)
(37, 73)
(79, 157)
(97, 193)

http://oeis.org/A217199

Comment: @tehforsch  it's [A005382](https://oeis.org/A005382)   The one you link to excludes those $p$ for which $2p-1$ is also on the list.

Comment: For the sake of curiousity : What are the largest known pairs $(p/2p-1)$ and $(p/2p+1)$ of prime numbers ?

Comment: The Bunyakovsky-conjecture also implies that there infinite many solutions for both pair-types.

Comment: @tehforsch Don't forget the pair $(2/3)$

Comment: I (knowing that the deduction of the existence of  an infinitude of primes having a specific form is an 
extreme difficult problem) encourage to yourself to study (or seach references, since I don't know if it was in the literature or has a good mathematical meaning since mine is a simple application/comparison using Euler-Fermat; and a similar approach is feasible using Wilson-Lagrange theorem) first if there are infinitely many integers $n\geq 1$ satisfying that $k^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\text{ mod }n$  and also $(k^{2})^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\text{ mod }(2n-1)$ for all integer $n<k<2n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but gives the solutions for $p,q<10,000$, generated by [BigZ for ANS-Forth](http://forthmath.blogspot.se/2017/09/bigz-new-top-level-instructions.html).

```
2 10000 :| q p | p is_prime q is_prime and if p 2* q 1+ = else false then ; create-set cr zet.  
{(2,3),(3,5),(7,13),(19,37),(31,61),(37,73),(79,157),(97,193),(139,277),(157,313),(199,397),(211,421),(229,457),(271,541),(307,613),(331,661),(337,673),(367,733),(379,757),(439,877),(499,997),(547,1093),(577,1153),(601,1201),(607,1213),(619,1237),(661,1321),(691,1381),(727,1453),(811,1621),(829,1657),(877,1753),(937,1873),(967,1933),(997,1993),(1009,2017),(1069,2137),(1171,2341),(1237,2473),(1279,2557),(1297,2593),(1399,2797),(1429,2857),(1459,2917),(1531,3061),(1609,3217),(1627,3253),(1657,3313),(1759,3517),(1867,3733),(2011,4021),(2029,4057),(2089,4177),(2131,4261),(2137,4273),(2179,4357),(2221,4441),(2281,4561),(2311,4621),(2467,4933),(2539,5077),(2551,5101),(2557,5113),(2617,5233),(2707,5413),(2719,5437),(2791,5581),(2851,5701),(3019,6037),(3037,6073),(3061,6121),(3067,6133),(3109,6217),(3169,6337),(3181,6361),(3187,6373),(3319,6637),(3331,6661),(3391,6781),(3499,6997),(3529,7057),(3607,7213),(3697,7393),(3709,7417),(3739,7477),(3769,7537),(3877,7753),(3967,7933),(4027,8053),(4051,8101),(4111,8221),(4159,8317),(4177,8353),(4231,8461),(4261,8521),(4339,8677),(4357,8713),(4447,8893),(4507,9013),(4567,9133),(4591,9181),(4621,9241),(4639,9277),(4801,9601),(4831,9661),(4861,9721),(4909,9817),(4951,9901),(4987,9973)} ok
```

Due to the comment:

```
7 10000 :| q p | p 2* q 1+ = if p is_prime q is_prime and else false then ; create-set  ok
:| q p | p ; transform-set zdup cartprod :| b a | a b >= ; filter-set  ok
:| b a | a b - 6 mod ; transform-set zet. {0} ok
```

And for the q-component:

```
7 10000 :| q p | p 2* q 1+ = if p is_prime q is_prime and else false then ; create-set  ok
:| q p | q ; transform-set zdup cartprod :| b a | a b >= ; filter-set  ok
:| b a | a b - 6 mod ; transform-set zet. {0} ok
```

Comment: It looks like the difference between primes you have listed is always divisible by 6 except first two pairs. I haven't checked all of them.

Comment: @usir0: you are right as far as I've tested. You could formulate a conjecture about this.

Comment: @usir0 The difference must always be divisible by $6$. Every prime greater than $3$ is congruent to $\pm1$ modulo $6$. If $p\equiv-1\pmod6$, then we have $q=2p-1\equiv3\pmod6$, so $q$ cannot be prime. Therefore $p\equiv1\pmod6$, so $q-p=p-1\equiv0\pmod6$.

Comment: @Théophile The true form for all prime numbers is a simple polynomial: ax+b. I might reveal this form next month in the question: Why number 9 is the first odd number not to be a prime number? All numbers whose factors are only prime numbers are also of this form.