# Are there infinitely many primes $q$, such that $\sigma(p^k) = 2q$, where $p$ is prime and $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ be the *classical sum of divisors* of $x$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Here is my question:

> Are there infinitely many primes $q$, such that $\sigma(p^k) = 2q$, where $p$ is prime and $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $p$ is prime, and $k \geq 1$ is an integer (satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), then we get
$$q=\frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2}=\frac{p^{k+1}-1}{2(p-1)}=\Bigg(\frac{p^{(k+1)/2} + 1}{2}\Bigg)\cdot\Bigg(\frac{p^{(k+1)/2} - 1}{p - 1}\Bigg)=\Bigg(\frac{p^{(k+1)/2} + 1}{2}\Bigg)\cdot\sigma(p^{(k-1)/2}),$$
whereupon we obtain, since $q$ is prime, that either
$$\text{Case (1):   } \frac{p^{(k+1)/2} + 1}{2} = 1$$
**XOR**
$$\text{Case (2):   } \sigma(p^{(k-1)/2}) = 1$$
holds.

---

We then get, from the first condition, that
$$\sigma(p^{(k-1)/2}) = q$$
which, together with $\sigma(p^k)=2q$, implies that
$$\sigma(p^k) = 2\sigma(p^{(k-1)/2})$$
Dividing both sides by $p^k$, and noting that $p^k = (p^{(k-1)/2})(p^{(k+1)/2})$, we obtain
$$I(p^k) = \Bigg(\frac{2}{p^{(k+1)/2}}\Bigg)I(p^{(k-1)/2})$$
But since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
$$1 < I(p^k) < \frac{5}{4}$$
and
$$1 \leq I(p^{(k-1)/2}) < \frac{5}{4}.$$

This implies that
$$\frac{4}{5} < \frac{2}{p^{(k+1)/2}} = \frac{I(p^k)}{I(p^{(k-1)/2})} < \frac{5}{4}$$
which means that
$$\frac{2}{5} < \frac{1}{p^{(k+1)/2}} < \frac{5}{8},$$
further giving
$$\frac{8}{5} < p^{(k+1)/2} < \frac{5}{2},$$
which implies that
$$\frac{64}{25} < p^{k+1} < \frac{25}{4}.$$

We get
$$\frac{39}{25} < p^{k+1} - 1 < \frac{21}{4}.$$
But since $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
$$p - 1 \geq 4.$$
In particular, we obtain the upper bound
$$q = \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{2(p - 1)} < \frac{21}{32},$$
which contradicts the requirement that $q$ must be prime.

---

We then get, from the second condition, that
$$k = 1,$$
and therefore that
$$\frac{p+1}{2}=q$$
where both $p$ and $q$ are primes.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Comment: It seems that it is not known if there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $2q-1$ is also prime according to [OEIS/A005382](https://oeis.org/A005382) and [Solve $2p = q + 1$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489862/solve-2p-q-1-where-p-and-q-are-prime).

Comment: Indeed, just as I expected, @mathlove.  Another open problem!  Could you please write out your last comment as an actual answer, so that I may be able to upvote and then accept?  Thanks!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is not known if there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $2q−1$ is also prime according to [OEIS/A005382](https://oeis.org/A005382) and [Solve $2p=q+1$ where $p$ and $q$ are prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2489862/solve-2p-q-1-where-p-and-q-are-prime).

Comment: This is a massive open problem that is at least as hard as the twin prime conjecture. You might have a look at Sophie Germain primes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Wikipedia page on Sophie Germain primes, @JoshuaStucky!  =)

Comment: @JoshuaStucky: I know this is a super late revert to your [comment from Sep 29 2021](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4262319/are-there-infinitely-many-primes-q-such-that-sigmapk-2q-where-p-is#comment8869054_4262468), but I think that $q$ is **not a Sophie Germain prime**, as it is $2q - 1$ that is also prime and **not** $2q + 1$.  (The proper terminology to use is actually [Cunningham chain of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain#Definition).